# Using pandas.DataFrame.apply to look up and replace values with values from a different DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames with the same DateTime index.

The first one is J:

```
            A     B     C
01/01/10    100   400   200
01/02/10    300   200   400
01/03/10    200   100   300
```

The second one is K:

```
             100    200    300    400
01/01/10     0.05  -0.42   0.61  -0.12
01/02/10    -0.23   0.11   0.82   0.34
01/03/10    -0.55   0.24  -0.01  -0.73
```

I would like to use J to reference K and create a third DataFrame L that looks like:

```
             A      B      C
01/01/10     0.05  -0.12  -0.42
01/02/10     0.82   0.11   0.34
01/03/10     0.24  -0.55  -0.01
```

To do so, I need to take each value in J and look up the corresponding value in K where the column name is that value for the same date.

I tried to do:

```
L = J.apply( lambda x: K.loc[ x.index, x ], axis='index'  )
```

but get:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I would ideally like to use this so that any NaN values contained in J will remain as is, and will not be looked up in K.  I had unsuccessfully tried this:

```
L = J.apply( lambda x: np.nan if np.isnan( x.astype( float ) ) else K.loc[ x.index, x ]  )
```

Comment: Your dataframes J and K have the same amount of rows and columns?

Comment: They share the same index, so will have the same amount of rows.  However, J will have fewer columns than K.

Comment: Please represent that in your example data. Now they both have the same amount of columns.

Comment: Updated the example data. Should be even more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to map the **new values**, then We return the DataFrame to original shape with [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
#if neccesary
#K = K.rename(columns = int)
L = (J.reset_index()
      .melt('index')
      .join(K.stack().rename('new_values'),on = ['index','value'])
      .pivot(index = 'index',
             columns='variable',
             values = 'new_values')
      .rename_axis(columns = None,index = None)
    )
print(L)
```

---

Or with [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
L = J.reset_index().melt('index')
L['value'] = K.lookup(L['index'],L['value'])
L = L.pivot(*L).rename_axis(columns = None,index = None)
print(L)
```

**Output**

```
             A     B     C
01/01/10  0.05 -0.12 -0.42
01/02/10  0.82  0.11  0.34
01/03/10  0.24 -0.55 -0.01
```

I think that `apply` could be a good option but I'm not sure, 
I recommend you see [`When should I want use apply in my code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) for label based indexing.

```
# if needed, convert columns of df2 to integers
# K.columns = K.columns.astype(int)
L = J.apply(lambda x: K.lookup(x.index, x))
```

```
             A     B     C
01/01/10  0.05 -0.12 -0.42
01/02/10  0.82  0.11  0.34
01/03/10  0.24 -0.55 -0.01
```